# Binary writing in C++, how to implement it?

Tags: c++, string, binary, char

**Update: Still none game me answer to my main question how to save string char by char or as a whole (I want to ignore the last Null)?**

Today I learned something new, which wasn't that clear to me.

I know how to save data as binary to a file, first I open it like this:

```
std::ofstream outfile(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
```

and then if I want to write a number I do the following:

```
outfile.write((const char*)&num, sizeof(int));
```

But, what about writing a `string`, how may I do this? char by char, or is there a faster method? Plus, what should the size of it be?

Comment: The buffer would be the pointer to the raw string contents (check out `c_str` in case you are talking about an `std::string`) and the size would be the string length.

Comment: (And there is no exception because it is perfectly valid to create a new file that didn't exist yet)

Comment: @CherryDT so so need for exception here?

Comment: If you're writing to binary files be absolutely sure you're writing in a consistent [endian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), not just whatever your architecture happens to use.

Comment: There is no flag that tells `std::ofstream` to NOT create a file if it does not exist. If you want that, you will have to use platform-specific APIs to open the file, such as `open()` (not `fopen()`!) without `O_CREAT`, `CreateFile()` with `OPEN_EXISTING` or `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau may you kindly see my edited question to help me find the bug?

Comment: @DanielRob You didn't show the code that re-opens the file for reading, or tries to actually read from it. But obviously, the reverse of `write()` is `read()`. So if the file opens successfully (with an `std::ifstream`), you can simply call `infile.read();` twice, with the same parameters you gave to `outfile.write()`.

Comment: If you have a new question created a new question. Do not keep editing your question and adding more questions to it.

Comment: It's good that you asked about writing `std::string`. A lot of people don't and are doomed to asking a much harder question after wasting a tonne of time on debugging. When I write a binary file I write the length of the file first in an integer of known and fixed size (`uint32_t`, for example) and then I'll write all of the characters in the string. Knowing how big the string is when you go to read it back out again can save a lot of time.

Comment: @user4581301 so what's the answer to my question, which method to use to save string?

Comment: Sorry about that. Hit enter too soon.

Comment: @user4581301 so you write char by char?, no faster method?

Comment: The write looks like `uint32 length = str.size(); outfile.write((char*)&length, sizeof(length)); outfile.write(str.c_str(), length); if (!outfile) {handle error};` Two take aways are always check the result of an IO transaction so you know whether or not it worked and can clean up if it didn't and prefer `sizeof(variable_name)` to `sizeof(variable_type)` so you can change the type of the variable later and not have to change as much code.

Comment: @DanielRob, show all your code, so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: What are you using to read the file after writing? If it's just a regular text editor you won't see anything. The numbers 1 and 2 don't contain any printable characters when viewed as ASCII or any other character encoding I know of..

Comment: Now that the question is better focused, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385569/4581301) should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

> But, what about writing a string, how may I do this? char by char, or is there a faster method? Plus, what should the size of it be?

you can use the **c_str()** method in std::string to get the char array exist inside the string object, as it returns **const char*** and it's the same type in **file.write()** parameters. And for the size you can get the string size using length() method from std::string. the code can be like :

```
string mystr = "hello world";
outfile.write(mystr.c_str(), mystr.length());
```

And for

```
outfile.write((const char*)&num1, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

it save something but it is not your integer, it does not save it. you may try this :

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num1), sizeof(num1));
```

and if it doesn't work you need to save your integer manually in a char array and write it to the file. you can convert your int to char using **char* _itoa(int value, char* str, int base);**  and for **char* str** size you can allocate a number of chars as many digit you have in your integer.

> PS: _itoa function belongs to C so using it in C++ may require to define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in the preprocessors

Comment: Note that `outfile.write(mystr.c_str(), mystr.length());` is nearly impossible to read back because there is no way to be sure when the string ends.

Comment: it depends on how he is going to read that file, he can read it line by line like this     
     std::getline(infile, line);
     'cout << line;  and just simply add \n to the end of the string he wish to write

Comment: I recommend writing the length of the string first, followed by the string's content.  This will allow to use block reading for the string.

Comment: `getline` would only work if a newline was written into the file immediately after the string or the string was at the end of the file. The first is a waste, might as well have written the null terminator when the string was written, and the second unlikely.

Comment: also this is another good Idea from @ThomasMatthews , he just will face saving integer each time that's maybe the down size or may happen an ambiguity between the length and text content.

Comment: @user4581301 it backs to him now to try to not waste the memory, like may add signs between the strings that he is sure, they are not a part of the text. or maybe something else. anyway thanks to the remark